# drop down filter not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I am trying to develop angularjs filter but I can't get result in the code below to show only one scope filter. How can I fix it? How to filter using  drop down box value . it filter two type like select box filter and text box value filter

```
<html >
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<title>search</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div>Search by Name: <input type="text" ng-model="filters.search"></div>


  <div> 
    <select ng-model="selectedCompany"  >
    <option ng-repeat="xi in array" value="{{xi.company}}">{{xi.company}}</option>
    </select>

    </div>

       <div ng-repeat="arr in array | filter:filters.search | filter:{company: filters.company}">
           <span ng-bind="arr.name"></span>
       </div>
       <h1>You selected: {{selectedCompany}}</h1>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.filters = {
        x: false,
        company: '',
        search: ''
    };

       $scope.actions = {
        updateyCompany: function () {
            if($scope.filters.y) {
                $scope.filters.company = 'y';
            } else {
                 $scope.filters.company = '';   
            }
        }
    };


    $scope.array = [
    {name: 'Tobias', lname: 'TLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Jeff', lname: 'JLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Brian', lname: 'BLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Igor', lname: 'ILname', company: 'y'},
    {name: 'James', lname: 'JLname', company: 'z'},
    {name: 'Brad', lname: 'BLname', company: 'y'}
  ];
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Thank you @basil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make below change and it should work (you have bind your select to "selectedCompany" so will have to use that in your filter as well):

```
 <div ng-repeat="arr in array | filter:filters.search | filter:{company: selectedCompany}">
           <span ng-bind="arr.name"></span>
       </div>
```